# Shopping Cart in asp.net core application does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, layout

I need to create a shopping cart in asp.net core application but when click button add to cart not working and Cart Icon not display and not save the items in cart.. can any one help me plzz :( ?

this is my method in Shopping Cart Model

```
 public string ShoppingCartID { get; set; }
    public List<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
    public static ShoppingCart GetCart(IServiceProvider service)
    {
        ISession session = service.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext.Session;
        var context = service.GetService<DataContext>();
        string cartId = session.GetString("CartId") ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        session.SetString("CardId", cartId);
        return new ShoppingCart(context) { ShoppingCartID = cartId };

    }
    public void AddToCart(Book book, int Amount)
    {
        var shoppingCartItem = _DataContext.shoppingCartItems.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Book.Bookid == book.Bookid && s.ShoppingCartId == ShoppingCartID);


        if (shoppingCartItem == null) {

            shoppingCartItem = new ShoppingCartItem
            {
                ShoppingCartId = ShoppingCartID,
                Book = book,
                Amount = 1,

            };
        _DataContext.shoppingCartItems.Add(shoppingCartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            shoppingCartItem.Amount++;
        }
        _DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

this is methods in my controller

```
    [Authorize]
    // GET: ShoppingCartController
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var items = _shoppingCart.GetShoppingCartItems();
        _shoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems = items;
        var ShopVM = new ShoppingCartViewModel
        {
            ShoppingCart = _shoppingCart,
            ShoppingCartTotal = _shoppingCart.GetShoppingCartTotal(),

        };
        return View(ShopVM);
    }

    [Authorize]
    public RedirectToActionResult AddToCart(int bookid)
    {
        var slecetBook = _bookRepository.Preffedbooks.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Bookid == bookid);
        if(slecetBook != null)
        {
            _shoppingCart.AddToCart(slecetBook, 1);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

this is shopping cart summary in razor page

```html
@if (Model.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.Count > 0 && SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li style="padding-top:8px;">
        <a asp-controller="ShoppingCart">
            <span class="fa fa-cart-plus"></span>
            <span id="cart-status">
                @Model.ShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.Count
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

Can anyone help me :( ??!

Comment: Do you have a <form method=post></form> tag wrapped around your button?

Comment: Can you share more about view,such as button add to cart and Cart Icon?What do you do when click the button,form post or use ajax to post data?